# Deserialising response from Wikipedia opensearch API

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

Could someone give me a hint as to the class structure to use to deserialise this Json response from the Wikipedia opensearch api:

```
[
  "test",
  [
    "Test",
    "Testosterone",
    "Test (assessment)",
    "Testicle",
    "Test-driven development",
    "Testosterone (medication)",
    "Testicular cancer",
    "Test cricket",
    "Tests of general relativity",
    "Test (wrestler)"
  ],
  [
   "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testosterone",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(assessment)",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testicle",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testosterone_(medication)",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testicular_cancer",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_cricket",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(wrestler)"
  ]
]
```

Just using the core .Net libraries i.e. no NewtsonSoft libraries etc.

Comment: have you tried a list of objects or an array of objects?

Comment: There's no `just using the core .NET libraries`. Up to .NET Core 2.2, .NET itself uses JSON.NET. JSON support was first added in .NET Core 3.1 with the `System.Text.Json` namespace

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This looks like an array of mixed strings and arrays, pretty much like a DataTable. You could handle it like an `object[][]` and treat each element in the outer array differently

Comment: Well this is what Wikipedia sends back as the Json response to a search query. I have not tried anything yet. I can normally handle a 'normal' Json response with curly brackets etc but this response has me flummoxed and I wouldn't know where to start!

Comment: @GaryK did you look at the documentation of the api -- what does it say it does?

Comment: I didn't know about the history of Json in .Net - but do now!. Ta.